# AutoCAD map server's text to ArcGIS Annotation - SAFE FME

Tags: esri-geodatabase, arcgis-desktop, fme-form, autocad-map

autocade
Software: SAFE FME
Geodatabase - enterprise geodatabase

we have autocad data stored in oracle database and wishes to port them over to ArcGIS Annotation (text).

We are unable to do so just by directly migration.

after investigation we realize that the autocad store the alignment in line or point form and text in context.

May I know if there is a possible way to migrate them over?

Comment: This [blog post](http://sunilupatil.blog.com/?p=61) may or may not be helpful.

Comment: Which license do you have for FME Workbench? ESRI/Intergraph http://www.safe.com/fme/fme-technology/fme-desktop/fme-editions/ +you need ArcGIS installed on the same computer for File Geodatabase annotation to be created.

Comment: We do have the license, it just that FME don't have the tool to directly convert them to annotation.